# Statistical Analysis in Blocking

Tags: statistics

I'm trying to fill in the missing subscripts for:

a) y_ _ _ = mu + alpha-sub1 + beta-sub(*2) + gamma-sub3 + (alpha-gamma)-sub(* _) + e-sub(_ _ _)

b) y-sub321 = mu + alpha-sub_ + beta-sub_ _ + gamma-sub_ + (alpha-gamma)-sub(_ *) + e-sub(* _ _)

c) y-sub(3_ *) = mu + alpha-sub* + beta-sub2 _ + gamma-sub_ + (alpha-gamma)-sub(_ 4) + e-sub(_ _ _)

Thanks

Comment: I find it hard to imagine what might have made you think that we'd be more likely to come up with an answer if you withhold the entire context.

Comment: This is for statistical analysis and blocking and ANOVA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below might be it. I filled in subscripts based on what I found in Intro to Statistical Methods and Data Analysis by Longnecker, Ott, page 1050. But this was somewhat of a shot in the dark bc I dont know what chapter this problem comes from and thus the type of experimental design implemented. I do not feel that there should be two subscripts in the beta term but perhaps I missed the context of this experimental design. Anyways, hope it helps and will edit this if I come upon something new.

a) y{123} = mu + alpha-sub1 + beta-sub(2) + gamma-sub3 + (alpha-gamma)-sub(12) + e-sub(123)

b) y-sub(321) = mu + alpha-sub3 + beta-sub(2) + gamma-sub1 + (alpha-gamma)-sub(32) + e-sub(321)

c) y-sub(324) = mu + alpha-sub(3) + beta-sub(2) + gamma-sub(4) + (alpha-gamma)-sub(34) + e-sub(324)